# Syntax error in script

Tags: fish

My script try execute *mvn clean install* in all projects but before it tried switch to dev branch and pull it.

```
successString="[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS";
file="mvnoutput";
red=$'\e[1;31m';
grn=$'\e[1;32m';
end=$'\e[0m';

function checkResult
    if grep -Fxq "$successString" $file 
    then
        echo -en "${grn}[${1}]Build ok${end}";
    else    
        echo "${red}[${1}]Error in mvn clean install${end}";
        exit 1;
    fi;
end

function pullAndSwitchDevBranch
    git checkout dev;
    git pull origin dev;
end 

cd api-pay-commons/;
pullAndSwitchDevBranch;
touch mvnoutput;
mvn clean install -U > mvnoutput;
checkResult PAY;
```

Why I received this error?

> line 17: end: command not found ./script.sh: line 20: syntax
>
> error near unexpected token `git' ./script.sh: line 20:`  git checkout dev;'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used the "fish" tag, so I'm assuming you are running this with the fish shell.

If so: This is not a valid fish script. Fish is explicitly not POSIX-compatible, so you might want to read up on the syntax. (If not, then please correct your tag)

red=$'\e[1;31m';

Fish does not use `var=value` to set a variable. It uses `set var value`.

Fish also does not have the `$''` style of quoting. Instead, backslash-escapes are interpreted *outside* of quotes.

So this would be `set red \e"[1;31m"`. Alternatively, fish offers the `set_color` builtin, which prints the escape sequence for a given color. So this could be `set red (set_color red)` (or you could call `set_color` later).

```
then
```

Fish does not use `if condition; then dosomething; fi`. It's `if condition; dosomething; end`.

```
echo -en "${grn}[${1}]Build ok${end}";
```

Fish does not use `"${var}"`. It also does not call the function arguments `$1` et al.

This would be something like `echo -ens "$grn" "[$argv[1]]" "Build ok" "$end"`.

```
exit 1
```

Fish currently does not allow `exit`ing from functions. You'll have to `return 1` and check the result from the outside.

Additionally, you're using semicolons all over the place, which is not typical style in any shell I'm aware of.

---

In case you are not using fish, but some POSIX-compatible shell (like bash), this is also not valid. The main (and possibly only) issue is that you are using `function something; dosomething; end`. In bash, that would be

```
 function something () {
      #dostuff
 }
```

And in pure POSIX, that would be

```
 something () {
     #dostuff
 }
```

Comment: exhaustive answer. fantastic!